# LDAP password policy minimum length is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, login, password, ldap

0
down vote
favorite
I have a working LDAP server. Next added password policy to LDAP server. My password ldif looks like this:

dn: cn=MyPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=XXX,dc=XXXX
cn: MyPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: device
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: 2.5.4.35
pwdMaxAge: 7862400
pwdExpireWarning: 6048000
pwdInHistory: 3
pwdCheckQuality: 2
pwdMinLength: 7
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 300
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
pwdReset: FALSE
it is successfully added to my LDAP server. But only Lock out and Lock out duration is working. Password minimum length is not working.

pam configuration
Server side configuration

pam.d/common-auth
auth [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth requisite pam_deny.so
auth required  pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-account
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]  pam_unix.so
account requisite    pam_deny.so
account required     pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-password
password [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=8
password requisite  pam_deny.so
password required  pam_permit.so

Client side configuration

pam.d/common-auth
auth [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so null_secure try_first_pass
auth [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth  requisite   pam_deny.so
auth  required    pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-account
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so 
account [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so 
account needs pam_deny.so
account required pam_permit.so

pam.d/common-password
password  [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password  [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
password  requisite  pam_deny.so
password  required   pam_permit.so

ldap.conf
pam_lookup_policy yes

Can you please let me know where I am gone wrong.